# subscribe does not exist on the typo void - profile edit form

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi so I am having this problem with my code and I don't know how to continue, plus my put method might not be the best

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BackendService } from 'src/app/services/backend.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/throw';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-profile',
  templateUrl: './edit-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-profile.component.css']
})
export class EditProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  public user: any = {};
  public accountDetails: any = {}

  constructor(
    private api: BackendService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    let profile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getUsers("profile"));
    console.log(this.accountDetails);
  }

  public onFormSubmit({ value, valid }: { value: any, valid: boolean }) {
    this.user = value;
    this.api.put("/users/editprofile", value.userId, false)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {

        console.log(data)
        localStorage.setItem("profile", JSON.stringify(data));

        location.href = "/profile"

      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you attach `BackendService` code?

Comment: Verify that the return type of `BackendService.put` is an `Observable`, to start with.

Comment: Error clearly says that you are not returning anything from `this.api.put("/users/editprofile", value.userId, false)` Read the error message before posting :)

Comment: @YongShun sure - https://pastebin.com/VkZNc5ia

Comment: From the link, the `put` method didn't return any value, but it throws an exception. Look like you didn't complete the code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a subscribe returns a void, this means that an observable is not returned by the called service.

To remedy this, the following solution works.

The Angular service is a wrapper for a call to the HTTP PUT on the Web API backend service, which is a `PUT` request to the URI:

```
/users/editprofile/{id}
```

The Angular service `BackendService` should provide a valid observable from the HTTP PUT request by calling:

```
this.http.put("/users/editprofile/" + id, payload)
```

Which will return an observable. (And `this.http` is an `HttpClient` instance)

So, a valid backend service method that returns a typed observable response would be:

```
editProfile(profiledata)
{
    return this.http.put<UserProfile>('/users/editprofile/' + 
       profiledata.id, profiledata);
}
```

Where `profiledata` is the interface of type `UserProfile` containing your data.

A call to the above service method will then be (can be varied slightly as needed):

```
const profiledata: UserProfile = { id: value.userId, flag: boolean }

this.api.editProfile(profiledata)
  .subscribe((data: any) => {

    console.log(data)
    localStorage.setItem("profile", JSON.stringify(data));

    location.href = "/profile"

  })
```

Following the above will correctly return subscribed data from the backend request observable.